# I have upgrade ubuntu 13.10 and now my localhost not working

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I have upgraded my ubuntu 13.10 and i have got my localhost not working. When i tried to restrt my apache2, it gave an error like bellow,

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                         [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/httpd.conf:
Invalid command '\xe2\x80\x9cServerName', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

How can i get localhost working agian... please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look over here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/362682/ubuntu-13-10-server-403-error-after-upgrading-to-apache2-4

I just ran into this same issue, and this fixed the problem for me.